# udev: renaming nic name may occur even after multi-user.target begin?

Tags: network-interface, udev, services

I am investigating a Linux server(CentOS7.9 kernel 5.4.179-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64) for a weird issue:
There is a pretty normal service:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/test.service
[Unit]
Description=tet
Before=frr.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the test.sh just configure networks, such as (simplied psuedo code)

```
show nic name by mac
```

It outputs modern nic name like `enp1s0f0`, instead of old style name `eth1` etc, this service works well on all other servers.

But it seems one day output an old style nic name such as `eth1`, but I could not trace back to that time to find related logs.

I did find the nic renaming log from dmesg, such as

```
[Fri Sep 15 00:38:24 2023] bnxt_en 0000:01:00.1 eth1: Broadcom BCM57414 NetXtreme-E 10Gb/25Gb Ethernet found at mem 4000200000, node addr 11:11:11:11:11:11
[Fri Sep 15 00:38:24 2023] bnxt_en 0000:01:00.1 enp1s0f1: renamed from eth1
```

So I guess there is a chance that the nic name was eth1.

#### I am wondering that may the nic renaming occur even after the multi-user.target begin ?(The multi-user.target is what most services be attached to)

The nic renaming happens in systemd-udevd.service, it was started pretty earlier,
but it continuously listen hardware events, so it seems the nic may appear slowly than expected, and may be renamed even after the test.service begin.

If this is true, then seems I have to use

```
udevadm settle
```

to ensure that no pending udev events so can may wait for nic renaming automatically.